# Can I write SWC plugins using Typescript/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, swc

In 2023 there is no info about JS/TS API available for SWC plugins system on the documentation page, only rust-written plugins. I went through many github issues to find it out with no luck. I even asked ChatGPT, and it says yes, there is such an API (ChatGPT data is limited by Nov 2021). But the latest post when it's mentioned is dated May 2022, and it seems this API was removed from SWC.

I see [this issue](https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/471) is the laters attempt to build this API, but I don't know if it was released.

So my question is - can I write SWC plugins in Typescript/Javascript?

Comment: I have never heard of any JS plugins for SWC, maybe ask gpt if it is sure…

Comment: ChatGPT is known to produce answers that are erroneous, or just plain wrong. Remember, it's just a chat bot. If you can't find something it's likely it doesn't exist, whatever ChatGPT says about it.

Comment: You're right, but my own search shows there were at least several attempts to create this API - take a look https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues/471. But I can't find if it was released.